# Convert a number from stringstream to string with a set precision

Tags: c++, precision, significant-digits

I would like to obtain a number from stringstream and set it to 5 significant figures. How do I do this? So far, this is what I have managed to come up with:

```
double a = 34.34566535
std::stringstream precisionValue;
precisionValue.precision(6) << a << std::endl;
```

However, this is not compiling. Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

It doesn't compile because `ios_base::precision()` returns `streamsize` (it's an integral type).

You can use [stream manipulators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip):

```
precisionValue << std::setprecision(6) << a << std::endl;
```

You'll need to include `<iomanip>`.

Answer (score 6):

`std::stringstream::precision()` returns a `streamsize`, not a reference to the stream itself, which is required if you want to sequence `<<` operators. This should work:

```
double a = 34.34566535;
std::stringstream precisionValue;
precisionValue.precision(6);
precisionValue << a << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 3):

The [`precision`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/precision) member function returns current precision, not a reference to the stringstream, so you cannot chain the calls as you've done in the snippet.

```
precisionValue.precision(6);      
precisionValue << a;
std::cout << precisionValue.str() << std::endl;
```

Or use the [`setprecision`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision) IO manipulator to chain the calls:

```
precisionValue << setprecision(6) << a;
std::cout << precisionValue.str() << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `std::setprecision` from header `<iomanip>`

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  double a = 34.34566535;
  std::stringstream precisionValue;
  precisionValue << std::setprecision(6);
  precisionValue << a << std::endl;
  std::cout << precisionValue.str();
}
```